# $R$ well-founded relation and $\forall y$, $\{x:xRy\}$ is finite implies $\forall y$, $\{x:xR^t y\}$ is finite (where $R^t$ is the transitive closure)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I am interested in proving the titular claim:

> $R$ well-founded relation and $\forall y$, $\{x:xRy\}$ is finite implies $\forall y$, $\{x:xR^t y\}$ is finite (where $R^t$ is the transitive closure)

After drawing a couple of pictures/graphs it reminded me of [Konig's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_lemma): "every tree that contains infinitely many vertices, each having finite degree, has at least one infinite simple path."

Assuming I have no knowledge of graphs and trees, is there a proof of the claim using the definition of well-founded?

This previous question I asked is related/useful:
[Transitive Closure of a Well-Founded Relation is Well-Founded (without Axiom of Choice)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347337/transitive-closure-of-a-well-founded-relation-is-well-founded-without-axiom-of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that for some $y$ the set $\left\{ x\mid xR^{t}y\right\} $
is *not* finite and set $a_{0}:=y$.

We have $R^{t}=R\cup (R^{t}\circ R)$ and
denoting $\hat{y}:=\left\{ x\mid xRy\right\} $we can write $\left\{ x\mid xR^{t}y\right\} =\hat{y}\cup\bigcup_{z\in\hat{y}}\left\{ x\mid xR^{t}z\right\} $.

Set $\hat{y}$ is finite so $\left\{ x\mid xR^{t}z\right\} $ must
be infinite for at least one $z\in\hat{y}$.

Pick out such $z$ and
name it $a_{1}$.

This can be repeated and a set $A:=\left\{ a_{n}\mid n=0,1,\dots\right\} $
is constructed with $a_{n+1}Ra_{n}$ for $n=0,1,\dots$.

Then $A$ has no $R$-minimal element which contradicts
that $R$ is well-founded.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is straightforward using well-founded induction.  So, suppose $y \in A$ (the domain of $R$), and assume the inductive hypothesis that whenever $z \mathrel{R} y$, then $\{ x \mid x \mathrel{R^t} z \}$ is finite.  Then whenever $x \mathrel{R^t} y$, then either $x \mathrel{R} y$ or there exists $z$ such that $x \mathrel{R^t} z$ and $z \mathrel{R} y$.  Therefore, $$\{ x \mid x \mathrel{R^t} y \} = \{ x \mid x \mathrel{R} y \} \cup \bigcup_{z \mid z \mathrel{R} y} \{ x \mid x \mathrel{R^t} z \}.$$
In this expression, the first set is finite by assumption, and the second term is a finite union of finite sets by the inductive hypothesis.  It follows that $\{ x \mid x \mathrel{R^t} y \}$ is also finite, completing what we needed to show to apply well-founded induction.