# ZF Set Theory - Showing a ≠ {{a}} for sets

Tags: set-theory

I believe the following is true, however I'm stuck trying to prove.

If a is a set, then a ≠ {{a}}

Indeed I believe the result is true for any number of brackets, i.e a ≠ {{{a}}} or {{{{a}}}} etc.

The case a≠{a} follows from the axiom of foundation (think also known as axiom of regularity)

Am guessing the proof involves foundation and perhaps induction?

Thanks :)))

Comment: Under the axiom of foundation it is also true that transitive closure $\overline{\in}$ is well founded (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1347337/75923) for instance). That might help. It demands that every non-empy set $a$ must have an element $b$ such that $a$ and the transitive closure of $b$ have empty intersection. Try that out in the case $a=\{\{a\}\}$ and you will meet a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you both!!!!!!